# PUT route with Node.JS

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, put

I am new here and I have a problem, I hope you can help me :).

I have the following AJAX in my client side that sends the data to update the database:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'PUT',
 url: host + '/database',
 data {
  name: 'MisterX',
  email: 'mister.x@gmail.com
 },
 sucess:function(sucess) {
  alert('sucess');
 },
 err:function(err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
});
```

Them, in my routes file i have:

```
app.put('/database', function(req, res) {
        require('data', function (data){
            var database = data;

            database.save(function (err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log('err', err);
                }
                res.status(200).json('ok');
                console.log('Database updated');
            });
        });
    });
```

This put route was completely done in theory, I do not know exactly how to take the data and updates them in my database

My schema:

```
var databaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        email: String,
    });
```

If someone can give me a direction, I appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: what is data in `require('data',...` ?

Comment: What are you using? Mongoosejs?

Comment: like i sad, its just theoric haha... i'm trying to take this from the ajax request: data {
  name: 'MisterX',
  email: 'mister.x@gmail.com
 },

Comment: Yesssss @sobingt.. i update the post.. you can see my schema..

Comment: you need to use a mongodb driver like [moongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/). Read on the above link.

Comment: i am already using mongoose, the database it's fine.. i need just update with the put request..@sobingt

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Also, you have some typos in your `AJAX` request.

Comment: This is not a very good question. You're not explaining exactly what the problem is. Are you just trying to figure out the flow of taking a put request and stuffing the data into mongo?

Comment: the problem is that my put it's not working because i don't know if he is wrong.. hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema file databaseScheme.js

```
....
var databaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nome: String,
    email: String,
});
...
```

route

```
/*
 * body-parser is a piece of express middleware that 
 *   reads a form's input and stores it as a javascript
 *   object accessible through `req.body` 
 *
 * 'body-parser' must be installed (via `npm install --save body-parser`)
 * For more info see: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser
 */
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
// instruct the app to use the `bodyParser()` middleware for all routes
app.use(bodyParser());

var Database = require(. / databaseScheme);
...
...
// As explained above, usage of 'body-parser' means
// that `req.body` will be filled in with the form elements
// Adds a new document
app.post('/database', function(req, res) {
    var database = new Database();
    database.name = request.body.name;
    database.email = request.body.email;
    database.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err', err);
        }
        res.status(200).json('ok');
        console.log('Database updated');
    });
});

// Update a document
app.put('/database/:id', function(req, res) {
    Database.findById(req.param('id'), function(err, database){
        database.name = request.body.user;
        database.email = request.body.user;
        database.save(function(err) {
             if (err) {
                console.log('err', err);
             }
             res.status(200).json('ok');
             console.log('Database updated');
       });
  });
});
```

Comment: do not forget about body-parsing middlewares like this one https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser